# Check if an object has been instantiated

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, instance

I keep running into an issue where I have to check whether an object has been instantiated for a class or whether a variable was created.

If, for example, the variable `frog` was never created

```
bool(frog)
```

I get an undefined error -- I probably should have used `type(frog)` there but same error an `bool(frog)` sounds funnier. Instead, if I write

```
'frog' in dir()
```

I'll get `False` as output. That's fine, but more commonly I run into an issue with objects where I'm conditionally instantiating them and I don't know what their name is (like they're in a list). Consider an object from

```
class beatle(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

b1 = beatle('Ringo')
```

Now, if this was happening only on certain occasions in a far away part of my code, and I didn't know the `object` was called `b1`, how could I check if an instance of `beatle` ever occurred? If I check `dir()`, I can't tell by the names if any member `dir()` is actually a beatle -- or possibly a list of beatles. The problem for me is that `dir()` is a list of `<class str>`, so I don't think it can provide what I need. I thought about just adding some `bool` type indicator in any conditional where the object is created but that seems too "hard-codish".

---

EDIT: There was a big edit here because I've been improving my coding since my last post, and I'm trying to avoid a ban from question asking, so  I apologize if this obfuscates anyone's original comments.

Comment: Why check within the class at the point of `Node` being instantiated? Why not just check it in your `main()` so that before you even try to instantiate `Node`, ensure `NodeGraph` exists first?

Comment: You could use `globals()` instead of `dir()` to get a collection of all objects in the global scope (but not in every possible scope). But it's not code that would pass any code review. Maybe you should explain the specific problem you are trying to solve with this approach? Class instances can be created and garbage collected in various scopes. It's better to explicitly pass some dependency to the callable that needs it, than to conjure some hard-to-debug implicit dependency inception.

Comment: I want this to be interactive, and mostly automated, so that, for example a user could add Node object to the graph at any time. But I see what your saying, still probably better. Quick question: should I be breaking down files and classes in Python the same way I would in a C++ project? You know how you separate headers or whatever from the actual functionality, protecting variables, etc.

Comment: @HåkenLid Not sure what this part means: "It's better to explicitly pass some dependency to the callable that needs it, than to conjure some hard-to-debug implicit dependency inception". Do you have any elementary examples?

Comment: What I mean is that you should pass everything a function or object instance needs as arguments. `def add(): return a + b` will work if `a` and `b` exists in the scope. But it's better to define a function like this. `def add(a, b): return a + b` where you explicitly pass the argument in. The same goes for more complicated things, such as classes. If `Node` needs a `NodeGraph`, then you can make it a required argument . `Node.__init__(self, node_graph)`.

Comment: To me, this question looks like a possible case of [the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/395013). There could be a simple and maintainable solution to your problem.